# Remove a single event from Calendar subscription

Tags: calendar, ical

I am subscribed to Apple's holiday calendar, which is very useful. However, some holidays are not of interest for me - is there a way to delete selected events manually while keeping the rest of the subscription?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually possible to download the subscription and then delete some events:

In the calendar app, right-click on the holiday calendar subscription and then "copy URL to clipboard". Paste this into a web browser, download the .ics file, double-click and finally we are there: All holidays for the next 10 years are imported, and all of the unwanted events can be deleted manually.

Answer (score 1):

No — subscribing to a calendar will add all the events to your calendar and it is not possible to hide any of them, just all of them by hiding the entire calendar.

Comment: I hoped that there was a way to download the entire list of the subscription and then delete some events out of it or something like that.

Comment: This is quite possibly the dumbest decision in the history of the universe; not deciding that this is a useful feature. I cry myself to sleep every night over this.

Answer (score 0):

I basically made copies of the holidays I wanted to show and unsubscribed from the calendar. IE, I duplicated the holidays for this province only and unsubscribed from the Canadian holidays so I wouldn't get holidays from every other province cluttering up my calendar. You can specify how you want the holiday to repeat by selecting yearly, say for Christmas, or custom, such as the third Monday every May for Victoria Day, by editing the settings for each holiday. It took me less than 5 minutes to add the holidayss for my province and delete the Canada holidays subscription; less time than it took to type this reply